# Bind variables in the enclosing function scope

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am reading *Python for Data Analysis* by Wes McKinney. I’m having trouble with this section:

Here’s a function that returns a function that keeps track of the arguments it has been called with:

```
 def make_watcher():
     have_seen = {}
     def has_been_seen(x):
         if x in have_seen:
             return True
         else:
             have_seen[x] = True
             return False
     return has_been_seen
```

Using this on a sequence of integers I obtain:

```
 In [496]: watcher = make_watcher()
 In [497]: vals = [5, 6, 1, 5, 1, 6, 3, 5]
 In [498]: [watcher(x) for x in vals]
 Out[498]: [False, False, False, True, True, True, False, True]
```

However, one technical limitation to keep in mind is that while you
 can mutate any internal state objects (like adding key-value pairs to
 a dict), you cannot bind variables in the enclosing function scope.
 One way to work around this is to modify a dict or list rather than
 binding variables:

```
 def make_counter():
     count = [0]
     def counter():
         # increment and return the current count
         count[0] += 1
         return count[0]
     return counter

 counter = make_counter()
```

In the text above, what does author mean by “you cannot bind variables in the enclosing function scope”? Please elaborate this statement.

Answer (score 2):

The example is intended to demonstrate what does work, but it doesn't show what wouldn't work. Here's an example of that:

```
def make_counter():
    count = 0
    def counter():
        # DOESN'T WORK
        count += 1
        return count
    return counter
```

This doesn't work because you're trying to re-bind `counter` to a new object, the integer 1, and you can't do that.

Comment: It would work if you replace `# DOESN'T WORK` with `nonlocal count`.

Comment: Yes, that is a Python 3 feature. I know the question is tagged with python-3 but maybe the book OP refers to is from 2.x.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for explanation. What is binding in this context?

Comment: Binding is when you assign a value to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because `int`s are immutable objects in Python -- once they are created they cannot be changed -- while `list`s are mutable. In Python it is better to think of variables as name tags rather than containers that hold a value. The name is just a nice reference to a block of physical memory where the value is actually stored. So when you are doing `count += 1`, you are really moving the name tag `count` to a new address in physical memory that has a value one more than the previous value of `count`. This can be seen by using [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id).

```
In [1]: a = 0

In [2]: id(a)
Out[2]: 140696027710384

In [3]: a += 1

In [4]: id(a)
Out[4]: 140696027710360
```

As you can see when we increment `a`, its id changes. Now let's do the same with a list:

```
In [1]: a = [0]

In [2]: id(a)
Out[2]: 4389820176

In [3]: a[0] += 1

In [4]: id(a)
Out[4]: 4389820176

In [5]: a.append(1)

In [6]: id(a)
Out[6]: 4389820176
```

And as you can see, the id of the list does not change when we increment a value in the list, nor does the id change when we add an element to the list.